# database string compare in postgresql not recognizing string length

Tags: php, string, postgresql

I am transferring data between servers, and need to change some links in our wiki database. I wrote a quick script that should be able to do this no problem. But When I run it, the `if($datacount)` condition never runs. This is probably something simple that I'm missing, but I can't see what the issue is.

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host= localhost port=5432 dbname=wiki user=user password=password");
$sql = "SELECT old_text FROM wiki_public.pagecontent LIMIT 10";
$go = pg_query($dbconn,$sql);
$i=0;
$string = 'sometext';
while($data = pg_fetch_assoc($go)) {
  $info = $data['old_text'];
  $count = strlen($string);
  $datacount = strlen($info);
  echo "Length: ".$datacount."<br/>";
  if($datacount != 0) {
    $position = strpos($string,$info);
    if($position !== false) {
      echo "The string ".$string." was found in row ".$i." and exists at position ".$position."The original content was: ".substr($info, $position,$count)."<br/>";
    }
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Thanks!
**EDIT**

When I remove the `$datacount` condition, this is my output

```
Length: 0

Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in D:\www\import\linksupadte.php on line 12
Length: 12
Length: 0

Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in D:\www\import\linksupadte.php on line 12
Length: 31
Length: 31
Length: 0

Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in D:\www\import\linksupadte.php on line 12
Length: 444
Length: 1614
Length: 153
Length: 125
```

Comment: What is the content of `$string`? (echo it together with `$datacount`).

Comment: $string is just some random text. It's weird because when I echo `$info` alongside `$datacount` I get something like Length: 144, `$info`=String(144){'onehundred44 characters of stuff'}, so there is content inside `$info` and `$count` is not always equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm declaring today a brain-free day for me.

```
<?php
# Database connection snipped.

# Let's say the database contains at least one row that's a substring
# of $string. Something like 'John', or '/123/'.
$string = 'John/123/456/789/012';
while($data = pg_fetch_assoc($go)) {

  $position = strpos($string, $data['old_text']);

  if ($position !== false) {
    echo "$string contains ".$data['old_text'];
  }
  else {
    echo "$string does not contain ".$data['old_text'];
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Got that part straight from the php strpos manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php That condition fires, I get an Empty delimiter error from strpos

Comment: @Ryan: Updated answer, after replacing my brain. I think it's now time for a nap.